# Trouble overwriting file content

Tags: file, go, overwrite

I've got trouble overwriting a files content with zeros. The problem is that the very last byte of the original file remains, even when I exceed its size by 100 bytes. Someone got an idea what I'm missing?

```
func (h PostKey) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := os.Create("received.dat")
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(f, r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Retrieve filesize
    size, _ := f.Seek(0, 1)
    zeroFilled := make([]byte, size + 100)
    n, err := f.WriteAt(zeroFilled, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Size: %d\n", size) // prints 13
    fmt.Printf("Bytes written: %d\n", n) // prints 113
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe share the content of the body? And what's the last byte that's not getting overwritten? Using your code I can't seem to be able to recreate your issue. [Here's the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0mASED0hSs)

Comment: You haven't provided code to reproduce the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writing to the file and trying to overwrite it in the same context, and so parts of the first write operation were still in memory and not yet written to the disk. By using `f.Sync()` to flush everything after copying the bodys content I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may occurred because the data is written into a same file (shared resource) inside an http handler, and the handler itself may be executed concurrently. You need to lock access to the file during data serialization (overwriting process). Quick solution will be:

```
import (
   "sync"
   //... other packages
)

var muFile sync.Mutex

func (h PostKey) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    muFile.Lock()
    defer muFile.Unlock()

    f, err := os.Create("received.dat")
    //other statements
    //...
}
```

If your server load is low, the above solution will be fine. But if your server needs to handle a lot of requests concurrently, you need to use different approach (although the rule is the same, lock access to any shared resource).